# Can I use /execute on a fishing rod hook that's in an entity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to detect when an entity is hooked by a fishing rod? I have a command block that uses:

> execute @e[name=unknown]

but when it hooks an entity it can't execute anything.

Comment: I updated my answer, this is now possible (but not 100% reliably).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original answer for 1.12: No, you cannot select fishing bobbers with commands.

---

New answer in 1.13+: Fishing bobbers can now be selected with `type=fishing_bobber`. There seems to be no way to 100% reliably detect when an entity is hooked, but you can for example check if it's nearby:

```
/execute at @e[type=fishing_bobber] run say @e[distance=.1..1]
```

Comment: While their command indicates usage of 1.12, I'll just leave a comment saying that in 1.13 there is an alias for bobbers: `minecraft:fishing_bobber`.

Comment: I'm trying to make it so when someone is caught with a fishing rod, it gives them slowness.

Regardless, thanks for the reply. I guess I'll just need to wait for the update.